# EMF induced in a wire travelling through a loop with B field inside

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I got a question like this: a wire is traveling through a loop with a shape as the picture shown, the wire has a **constant velocity v**, and there is a uniform magnetic field point into the loop. Yet the picture doesn't show the right side of the loop, it is connected with a resistor and thus they construct a closed circuit. The loop has a **radius R** and **magnetic field B**. Asking for the **emf** induced in the wire.

[image: question]

I have tried to use Faraday's law for this question:
$$|\epsilon| = |-\frac{d}{dt}\int \vec B \cdot d\vec A|$$
Since the magnetic field B is uniform and $d\vec A \parallel \vec B$, I got:
$$|\epsilon| = \frac{d}{dt} B \int d\vec A = \frac{d(BA)}{dt} = B\frac{d(\pi R^2)}{dt}$$
Since the wire is traveling with a constant velocity v, and the magnetic field only appear inside the loop, by Newton's Laws:
$$2R=vt$$
So $$R=\frac{vt}{2}$$
Then continue with Faraday's Law,
$$|\epsilon| = B\pi\frac{d}{dt} \frac{v^2 t^2}{4}$$
Finish the derivative, I got:
$$|\epsilon| = \frac{B\pi v^2 t}{2} = B\pi vR$$
The last step is rewrited by $R=\frac{vt}{2}$

Above is what I did for this question. However, the answer given is $|\epsilon| = \frac{B\pi vR}{2}$
I don't know where the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: (1) $\frac{d(\pi R^2)}{dt} =0$ because $R$ is a constant. I'd abandon this route, or rethink it. (2) I think they want the $mean$ value of the emf as the wire traverses the loop (3) Forget the odd shape; it's a circular patch with a uniform B field at right angles to it. (4) You don't need calculus.

Comment: Yes, this question doesn't need calculus, but I would like to see what would happen if I did it in the "calculus" way. Which way should I rethink? And why there is a mean value of the emf? Is the emf changing?

Comment: The emf in a wire moving at speed v in a direction at right angles to itself and to the B field is $\mathscr E = B \ell v$ in which $\ell$ is the length of the part of the wire in the field and therefore cutting flux. As the wire moves through the circular patch, $\ell$ keeps changing, being a maximum as the wire passes through the diameter position. The 'calculus way' is a very long-winded way of determining the mean emf, which is the answer that you quote.

Comment: The $\mathscr E = B \ell v$ formula is arguably more fundamental for motional emf than $\mathscr E = -\frac {d(BA)}{dt}$. To show that they are equivalent, in the context of your question, the flux cut in a time dt is $d(BA) = B \ell v dt$ since the flux-penetrated area swept out by the wire in time $dt$ is $\ell \times v dt$, $\ell$ being the length of the circle chord formed by the wire at time $t$. $\mathscr E$ is the emf at time $t$.

Comment: I got it, thank you!